# Which /boot and /etc are used by Grub2 when there are multiple OS?

Tags: grub2

I have two partitions which contain grub configuration files (Debian and Ubuntu).

I know I need to configure using files in `/grub` or `/etc` but on which partition?

Answer (score 0):

Generally both grub installations will coexist peacefully. It may depend on the location to which you installed grub e.g. `/dev/sdX` may take precedence over `/dev/sdYz` (you should really only have one grub installed at the base of a single disk i.e. `/dev/sdY`). In my experience though the grub install that has had `update-grub` ran against it most recently will take priority.

You should boot into the system you prefer to take precedence and make your desired configuration changes there. You can then regenerate your `grub.cfg` file and see if the changes hold. On Debian based systems you need to set your desired configuration options in `/etc/default/grub`. This includes things like default OS and timeout before booting. See the [GNU documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Simple-configuration.html) for an overview of the available options. You can then run the following command to apply these changes.

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

There is also a wrapper script `update-grub` that will do the same thing for you. Finally, just reboot your machine and see what has worked for you.